# mysql query - where clause active only for the selection of a particular field

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Let's say we have 2 tables:

**t1**: with columns **t1.doc_id**, ...
looks like this:

| **t1.doc_id** |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

**t2**: with columns **t2.from_doc_id**, **t2.to_doc_id**, **t2.flag**, ...
looks like this

| **from_doc_id** | **to_doc_id** | **flag** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | null |
| 1 | 101 | null |
| 2 | 100 | null |
| 3 | 8 | set |

I wanted to get a query result like this:

| **t1.doc_id** | **refs** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100, 101 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 |  |

Basically, wherever `flag` is `null`, i want to collect all `to_doc_id` and concatenate them in a string if `flag` is not `null`.  Like the first two results in the example above.

If `flag` is not null (like third row in `t2` example), I still want to get the `3` in the query result, but the `refs` field should not contain `8`.

with a query:

```sql
SELECT t1.doc_id, group_concat(t2.to_doc_id) AS refs
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.from_doc_id = t1.id 
WHERE t2.flag is null
```

... i miss the last line entirely, I only get the first two lines from the expected result.

So I guess, what I want, is to use `WHERE t2.flag is null` in `group_concat`, but to ignore the t2.flag when I get the `t1.doc_id` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` inside `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT from_doc_id
      ,group_concat(CASE WHEN flag IS NULL THEN to_doc_id ELSE '' END) AS refs
FROM yourtable t1
JOIN yourtable2 t2 ON t1.doc_id = t2.from_doc_id
GROUP BY from_doc_id
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95a7b02e94317ba8713be5d723a53617)

Comment: indeed, this is the best solution. It is in the same direction that Yusuf was going too, but the `CASE` was outside the `GROUP_CONCAT`. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :) @ValentinDumitru. You can mark only one answer as resolved but also you can upvote multiple answers(by clicking up arrow just above the tick mark) if you think it helped you.

Comment: i did that already, but since my reputation score is low, my upvote was recorded but not shown publicly.